# is it possible to show a fractional number in the output of c++?

Tags: c++, fractions

I want to calculate some formula and show the results in a fractional number, but as I know c++ converts them to floats. probably, is there any library or method to show them just fractional?
 for example, I wanna have 9/5 in output not 1.8

Comment: MPIR and GMP can  both do this

Comment: the problem inst the printing but you need a representation of fractions, once you have that printing them is simple. Can you keep `9` and `5` as seperate values or do you only have the `1.8` and need to get numerator and denominator from that?

Comment: If your floats follow IEEE 754, I think you can print `fraction / 2^exponent` easily.